# Azure Powershell Runbook converting excel file in blob storage to csv

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am trying to call an Azure Powershell Runbook as a webhook from Data Factory. This PowerShell converts excel(.xlsx) to CSV which resides in blob storage. The script currently only changes file format from .xlsx to .csv and hence is not properly converted to CSV. When previewed in the data factory, this CSV file is encoded. What is the proper way of converting xlsx to csv Using Azure PowerShell runbook or python. I want to automate this in Azure. This is what it is currently doing:

```
`#Get the files to convert from excel container
$rawFile = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $rawFilesContainer -Context $storageAccount -Blob $fileName
$rawFileName = $rawFile.Name
$rawFileWithoutExtension = $rawFile.Name.Substring(0, $rawFile.Name.IndexOf('.')) 
$csvFile = $rawFileWithoutExtension + '.csv'

#Convert and save in csv container
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcBlob $rawFileName -SrcContainer $rawFilesContainer -DestBlob $csvFile -DestContainer $outputContainer -Context $storageAccount -DestContext $storageAccount -Force`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following route

1.Store your Power-Shell script .ps on a blob container.
2.Create a C# console app to execute the power-shell script stored in the blob.
3.In ADFv2 create a pipeline,configure a custom activity to run the console app you created.
4.Schedule it using a trigger.

You will need a storage account,batch account,batch windows vm pool inside the batch account.